# Ways to transfer data to OMS

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-sql-server, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to gather all the possibilities through which I can import the data occasionally to OMS in Azure from Azure SQL database and Azure App Insights.

The only possibility that I could find is using the **SQL Server connector** for importing data from SQL server to OMS and using **Application Insights connector** for importing the data from App Insights to the OMS.

Please let me know if there are any other approaches available to achieve this.